# Why is the concatenation of a set of files greater than the sum of the parts?

Tags: file, filesystems

In an obscure way, it is a programming question. I concatenated several sets of text files in the range of 1MB and found that in each case the concatenated file size was much larger than the sum of the individual files by a large extent (2x-4x times more, even greater for Windows7).

Why is this?

Comment: maybe you could describe how you concatenated, with some code example? that way its easier to help

Comment: How did you concatenate them, and how are you measuring file-size?

Comment: If they're text files, open them in Notepad and look for duplicated data. I suspect you've concatenated some of them more than once, or something.

Comment: You need to post some code, so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: ASCII or UNICODE text files (all same?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IT was probably read in ASCII, and written in Unicode. Open the file in a binary/hex viewer to confirm.